# Accessing a UIView from SKScene

Tags: swift

I have a UIView

`@IBOutlet weak var whiteBox: UIView!`

in my UIViewController class. Is there a way to access it from my SKScene class?

Comment: Is the scene in an `SKView`? If so, what is the relationship between the `SKView` and the view controller? Is the `SKView` in the view controller's view hierarchy or outside it?

Answer (score 0):

In the `SKScene` add these initializers (assuming that your `UIViewController` is called `GameViewController`)

```
var viewController: GameViewController
init(size: CGSize, parent: GameViewController) {
    self.viewController = parent
    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

And in your `GameViewController` replace the current `GameScene` initializer with this (assuming that your `SKScene` is called `GameScene`)

```
let scene = GameScene(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!, parent: self)
```

To access the `UIView` use this:

```
viewController.whiteBox
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for the 'self.viewController = parent' part, I get an error saying "value of type GameScene has no member 'viewController'", any way to fix that?

Comment: Just add this line `var viewController: GameViewContoller `

Comment: goddamit you typed "GameViewCONTOLLER" instead of "GameViewCONTROLLER" that's why it wasn't working, lol (I copied the code). Thank you very much for the help :3